# How to open tk window in another thread (Calling Tcl from different apartment)

Tags: python, tkinter

I haven't found any answers relevant to opening another non-blocking window (=thread) in tkinter, at least not acting like I want.

Here is a snippet from the code that throws a 'Calling Tcl from different apartment' error.

```
# controller.py
def get_db(self, x, y):
    if self.model.df is None:
        self.show_error("Merci de renseigner un plan de quai.")
        return
    try:
        self.model.x = x
    except ValueError as error:
        self.show_error(error)
        return
    try:
        self.model.y = y
    except ValueError as error:
        self.show_error(error)
        return

    thread = Thread(target=self.view.show_map, args=[self.model.df])
    thread.start()
    self.view.reset()

# view.py
# function that should open another window which display a map composed 
#  of buttons
def show_map(self, df):
    display_map(self.parent, df)

# map_button.py

def display_map(parent, df):
    print(df.shape)
    root = Tk()
    frame=Frame(root)
    Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
    Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
    grid=Frame(frame)
    grid.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W, column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame, 7, weight=1)
    Grid.columnconfigure(frame, 0, weight=1)

    w = display_map_as_button(df, frame, df.shape[1], df.shape[0])
    tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: there's only one root and in whichever thread that root is in, you should have all the other windows/widgets in that thread too, you also should only call tkinter methods for any widgets from that one thread

Comment: But then how do I manage to create another window that doesn't block the execution of the rest of the code ?

Comment: creating new windows won't block the execution really, also there should be only one `Tk` instance (the root), other windows should be `Toplevel`s

Comment: First of all, you should use `root.mainloop()` instead of `tkinter.mainloop()`. Second, `tkinter` doesn't play nice with threads. Third of all, you only need to call `.mainloop()` once no mater how many `Tk()` windows you have.

Comment: Managed to do it! Thank you guys